# How to play a youtube videos using urls in honeycomb devices?

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-3.0-honeycomb

Now i am loading the youtube videos in WebView. This is working fine in 4.x and later versions, but i want to implement for honeycomb devices also. I don't know how to play youtube videos using flash in honeycomb . please help me.

This is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mContentView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mTargetView = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.target_view);

    myChromeClient = new MyChromeClient();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            video_view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                video_view.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
             }

            video_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            video_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            video_view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

            video_view.setWebChromeClient(myChromeClient);
            try {
                video_view.loadDataWithBaseURL("", getHTML(), mimeType, encoding, "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Status", "exception");
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public String getHTML() {
    String html = "<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"ytplayer\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/"
            + "bvraNCHUpuE"
            + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\">\n"
            + "</iframe>\n";
    return html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because WebView(prior Android 4.0) does not supports Flash videos.

But don't worry youtube API v3 supports all videos.

Download From [HERE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/)

Comment: is it possible to play with out using API?

Comment: Nope it is not possible without latest youtube API.